# "Conversion to base64Binary failed" Error using MapForce to POST to Web Service

Tags: map-force

In Altova MapForce, when sending XML to the Body of an HTTP POST (a Web Service call) through a `mime-entity` function, it generates an error "Conversion to base64Binary failed for '`<?xml...`'". How do I send XML from a string into a web service call Body connector without generating that error?

[image: MapForce map showing XML string being sent to POST and generating error]

Answer (score 1):

The [`mime-entity`](https://www.altova.com/manual/Mapforce/mapforceenterprise/index.html?mff_lib_mime_mime-entity.htm) function expects binary data which is Base64-encoded. That encoding can be performed using the [`charset-encode`](https://www.altova.com/manual/Mapforce/mapforceenterprise/index.html?mff_lib_mime_mime-entity.htm) function with a suitable encoding such as "utf-8".

[image: MapForce map showing charset-encode function encoding data for mime-entity function]